# Displaying a String Multiple times using * operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I “multiply” a string (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c)

Is there a simple way to display a String multiple times by using something like `str * 2`?

In other words, is there a way to have:

```
int numTimes = 500;
String str = "\n";
String body = ""
for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
{
    body = "Hello" + str;
}
```

Without needing the for loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c/7394020#7394020 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no such operator.

you could do

```
body = "Hello" + String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, numTimes).Select(i => str));
```

but that's internally still looping.

Comment: @Gabe to return the variable `str`.

Comment: I see, it looks like I misread your post. I was expecting to see `Enumerable.Repeat` so I didn't understand why there was a `Select`. Obviously since you're using `Enumerable.Range` instead then you do need the `Select`.

Comment: @Gabe I so rarely use `Enumerable.Repeat()` I forget about it's existence. This would be one case where it would be very appropriate.

Comment: I suppose I should add that `String.Concat(...)` is somewhat more concise than `String.Join("", ...)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this, without simply *hiding* the loop or some other contrived example, is no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
No, not out of the box.
Yes, you can make an extension method to do that pretty easily.
See thread on string extension methods here [C# String Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587608/c-string-operator-overloading)

It would still be looping, so you should use StringBuilder, not pure concatenation, if possible, especially if you don't know how many times it will loop. Strings are immutable, so 500 loops is an awful lot of temp strings in memory.